# Portable INotifyDataErrorInfo, ValidationContext and Validator.TryValidateObject

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.ios, xamarin, portable-class-library

I'm trying to use INotifyDataErrorInfo, ValidationContext and Validator.TryValidateObject and I keep getting stack overflow exceptions. Visual Studio locks up and all there is to do is kill it via Task Manager. I can't even step into the property. I have tried moving the code outside the class into a separate method and it does the same thing, I can't even step into the method to see which line is causing the lockup.

This appears in the Output window:

```
mono-rt: Stack overflow in unmanaged: IP: 0x1516f9, fault addr: 0xbff88fdc
Unhandled Exception:

System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.
```

My setup is:
Win8 project and Xamarin.iOS Universal project both referencing a Profile7 PCL which contains a bunch of ViewModels.

I have a simple view model which implements INotifyDataErrorInfo (for the Win8 binding). No issues here. The iOS project will simply use the "HasErrors" property, etc...

Here's a full class which causes the stack overflow when run in the iOS 7.1 Simulator:

```
public class SimpleValidation : INotifyDataErrorInfo
{
    #region INotifyDataErrorInfo Members

    public event EventHandler<DataErrorsChangedEventArgs> ErrorsChanged;

    public System.Collections.IEnumerable GetErrors(string propertyName)
    {
        IList<string> list = new List<string>();

        return list;
    }

    public bool HasErrors
    {
        get
        {
            ICollection<ValidationResult> validationResults = new  List<ValidationResult>();

            var vx = new ValidationContext(this);

            if (Validator.TryValidateObject(this, vx, validationResults))
            {
                return false;
            }

            return true;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    [Required(ErrorMessage="Dude, where's my car?!?")]
    public string SimpleProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Are these types not compatible? I thought System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations had been ported?

Any help much appreciated.

Cheers,
Krishna

Comment: Ok, I think I found it, not 100% sure.  I managed to get a stack trace from VS and it shows the Validator is calling into "HasErrors".  Which triggers the Validator again, which calls into "HasErrors" again.

Comment: I would have thought that the Validator would only inspect properties that were annotated?

Comment: I have a work around, and that is to call Validator.TryValidateObject from outside the "HasErrors" property.  Seems to work fine then.  I'm pretty sure there's a bug there, the Validator class should not be interrogating properties that are not adorned with a validation attribute.  It works as expected using the full .NET framework, just not using Xamarin.